# Replace AngularJS for Angular 5 in eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, angular, tomcat, angular5

I have an webapp in AngularJS and I want to redo it in Angular 5.

The webapp is in AngularJS and I have deployed in eclipse on a Tomcat server and has made the back in Java.

I have made my new webapp in Angular 5 also in eclipse using webeclipse installed by Angular Cli and it is deployed in the server that installs by default.

Now I would like to use the back of the original project (AngularJS) and for that I have doubled the project, but I do not know how to eliminate the project in AngularJS and replace it with Angular 5. Can you help me?

Comment: If I have understood correctly your question simply undeploy the Angular 5 application from Tomcat and deploy the other one

Comment: Thanks a lot... but maybe I don't explain in good way (my english is terrible, sorry).... I have the AngularJS deploy in Eclipse in a Tomcat server with backend in Java.

In the other hand I have a other workspace in Eclipse where I deploy a Angular5 app in a angular cli  without back (at least I don't  do any).... and I now want to put the angular5 app in the tomcat with the Java backend to can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that finally uses has been to separate the front from the back and leave the Java (back) in eclipse and the Angular (front) in Visual Studio Code. The problem has been the CORS, but that is solved in other Stack Overflow questions.